# Launchctl says my launch agent has already been bootstrapped, but it didn't run when expected and I also can't kickstart it. What's wrong?

Tags: macos, launchctl, macos-monterey, launch-agent

So I have a launch agent plist that's supposed to run every Monday and then it runs an executable file named `sync-stuff.sh`, which in turn dumps a Brewfile with `brew bundle dump --force` in a very specific location on my iCloud drive.

Well it didn't run this morning and I don't understand why. When I try to bootstrap it once more I get this:

```bash
$: launchctl bootstrap user/$(id -u) Library/LaunchAgents/com.me.backup.mackup.plist
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
$: sudo !!
$: sudo launchctl bootstrap user/$(id -u) ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.me.backup.mackup.plist
Password:
/Users/evert/Library/LaunchAgents/com.me.backup.mackup.plist: service already bootstrapped
Bootstrap failed: 17: File exists
$: sudo launchctl enable user/$(id -u)/com.me.backup.mackup
$: sudo launchctl kickstart -p user/$(id -u)/com.me.backup.mackup
Could not find service "com.me.backup.mackup" in domain for uid: 501
```

So then I thought, okay I'll `boutout` and then `bootstrap` again, just to try.

```bash
$: sudo launchctl bootout user/$(id -u)/com.me.backup.mackup
Boot-out failed: 3: No such process
```

So when I bootstrap it says `service already bootstrapped`, but it doesn't run when it's supposed to, and when I try to kickstart it, it says `Could not find service "com.me.backup.mackup" in domain for uid: 501` and same happens when I try to `bootout`.

So by now I have no idea what the status of my LaunchAgent is or how to get it to work.
Can anybody help please?

Oh yeah I'm on macOS Monterey and the legacy `load` and `unload` subcommands seem to have finally been removed, so that's why I'm not using them anymore.

### Edit

Could it be that my `com.me.backup.mackup.plist` is invalid?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.me.backup.mackup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>exec $HOME/Scripts/sync-stuff.sh --launch-agent</string>
      </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key> 
    <dict> 
        <key>Weekday</key> 
        <integer>1</integer> 
    </dict>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <string>Background</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same `Boot-out failed: 3: No such process` error.

Try changing "user" to "gui":

`sudo launchctl bootout gui/$(id -u)/com.me.backup.mackup`